# Crontab expression for a 8 and a half hour range

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cron

Crontab to run a job every minute from 11pm to 7:30am

I have this so far which is every minute from 11pm to 7:00am
the problem is the half hour.

```
* 23,0-7 * * *
```

You can play around with it here [crontab_guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_23,0-7_*_*_*)
Any ideas?

Comment: Might be easier to do one cron from 11-7:00 and another for 7:01-7:30.

Comment: yep. Im thinking the same

Comment: @Dunski : *,0/30 23,0-7 * * * (“At every minute and every 30th minute from 0 through 59 past hour 23 and every hour from 0 through 7.”) have a try with this crontab expression.

Comment: @HemanthKumar Nice try:) Unfortunately that only brings me to 7am. It needs to go to 7:30am

Comment: @Dunski : This will go to till 07:30 am also but the only doubt is it will stop or not .
if it doesn't stop at 07:30 am then it will automatically stop at 07:59 min.

Comment: @HemanthKumar OK thank you. I will see if I can test it somehow. It mush stop at 7:30. that is critical. I'l let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Dunski : Just have a test run  and Check if it's stopping or not. I too will work this concern to get it stop at 07:30am only.

Comment: @HemanthKumar according to crondrive thats not a valid cronline https://www.crondrive.com/test-cron-expression?utf8=%E2%9C%93&expression=*%2C0%2F30+23%2C0-7+*+*+*&time_zone=UTC&commit=Test

Comment: @Dunski : As per Crontab Guru above is working but as per crondrive use this expression `*,0-30 23,0-7 * * *`  it's working, i have tested.

Comment: @HemanthKumar from what I can see the cron job with both these examples will continue on until 8:am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dunski : I have checked in many ways this `*,0-30 23,0-7 * * *` expression could stop at 07:59 min only but not yet 07:30 am.

As @jordanm suggested we have only a way to run two jobs from :

11 pm to 7 am expression `* 23,0-7 * * *` (“At every minute past hour 23 and every hour from 0 through 7.”) and then

7 am to 7:30 am `0-30 7 * * *` (“At every minute from 0 through 30 past hour 7.”).